# What view of the Falcon 9 does this screenshot show?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9

Watching SpaceX webcasts, I've noticed this particular view during the Falcon 9's flights. No one I've asked has any idea what's shown here. (Though one person commented that it looked like a Minecraft Nether Portal!)

[image: Screencast]

What view of Falcon 9 is depicted here?

Comment: From the inside of the second stage LOX (cryogenic liquid oxygen) tank. See [SpaceX CRS-5 Launch: What is the footage that appears to contain bubbles?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/7737/49)

Comment: Excellent. I couldn't find that via Google; probably bad keywords on my part. Closing this question.

Comment: Please don't delete it. Different wording might help others find answers too. Thanks!