# SpaceX Webcast - What is visible in this clip?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, fuel

I've just watched the SES-9 Launch Webcast and was wondering what is visible at about [37:15](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=muDPSyO7-A0&t=2235)?

[image]

Does the Falcon 9 have cameras in the kerosene (or LOX) tank?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that's a look inside the kerosene or LOX tank. SpaceX has cameras inside both tanks. [This question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/7737/spacex-crs-5-launch-what-is-the-footage-that-appears-to-contain-bubbles/7738#7738) has more detail (incl. how you can see which tank you're looking at).

Comment: The link is very informative!